# Third - party applications can get signed for signature permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

Following the manifestation file https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml, we have some protection levels of permissions, such as
 signature|system|development, signature|system, system|signature, signature|development|appop, signature|privileged, signature|installer, signature. I know that the permissions with ".*|system|.*" are used only for the system/manufacturer applications. But for "signature", "signature|development|appop" levels, I wonder whether a third-party application can get the certificate to use them? Because I saw that Facebook has the permission "Battery_stats" in its list of permissions. I tried to find the information to confirm this question, but found no clear confirmation.

Comment: "I wonder whether a third-party application can get the certificate to use them?" -- only via some sort of licensing deal with the device manufacturer in question.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks a lot for your reply :)